# how to make the parent window blank during the onload?

Tags: javascript

When i type the URL in the browser the login.jsp gets evaluated and a child window(with diasabled toolbar ) is opened and the parent window gets closed.

wat i want is when i type the url in the browser and click go i dont want to display any information of login.jsp page to be dispalyed in the parent window.. i want only in the child window......

i dont have any idea of using another jsp...

can someone help me wit the code or ideas....

the code i hav written is pasted below.

**Login.js file**

```
function focus(){
    window.onload=ifocus();           
    document.LoginFB.strUserid.value="";
    document.LoginFB.strPassword.value="";
    document.LoginFB.strUserid.focus();
}

function ifocus(){
    if(!window.opener){
        window.opener='top';
        window.close();
        window.open('http://localhost:8080/jsp/Login.jsp','tr','width=1250,height=700,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,hbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,scrolling=yes, resizable=yes');
    }else{
    return;
}
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<body onload=javascript:focus()>
```

Comment: There is one close bracket missing in `ifocus` function, I intentionally left as is.

Comment: im concerned abt how to make the parent window blank or close it without opening it........

Comment: All the websites that do what you want to do are fugly, annoying, and so 90s that it makes you doubt the ability of the developers in more sensitive areas, like security. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't get the dance with the onload functions, but i would do this:

```
function focus(){
  if(!window.opener){
    window.open('http://localhost:8080/jsp/Login.jsp','tr','width=1250,height=700,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,hbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,scrolling=yes, resizable=yes');
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "";
    //or
    window.close();
    //but then you may get an alert...
  }else{ //child
    document.LoginFB.strUserid.value="";
    document.LoginFB.strPassword.value="";
    document.LoginFB.strUserid.focus();
    return;
  }
}


<body onload=javascript:focus()>
```